# Why is set-option query count so high in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have recently started seeing high amount of set-option query count in mysql. Its around 15k/sec

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%set%';
+-------------------+------------+
| Variable_name     | Value      |
+-------------------+------------+
| Com_reset         | 0          |
| Com_set_option    | 5472249432 |
| Com_show_charsets | 31         |
| Com_stmt_reset    | 0          |
+-------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However nothing like "set" operation is seen in the "show processlist"

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHmxd.png)
Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: "`COM_SET_OPTION` is a special command in the MySQL protocol which is currently used exclusively to enable or disable multi-statement support as detailed .https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-set-option.html Some database clients (such as certain versions of the MySQL libraries for PHP) will do this every time a new connection is established" source https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86467/27070

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. So does that mean set-option count going high is normal and can be ignored right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland the reason why this question arise was that this count was not noticed before and significantly started increasing suddenly.

Comment: if it was not noticed before how do you know it was significantly increasing

Comment: @RaymondNijland please see the Image i have added to the question as link. The count should have been present but not at as much as it is now since last week Thanks

Comment: dont know from what application that image is.. Maybe somebody change the config from that application so it displays the `Com_set_option` to??

Answer (score 0):

**COM_SET_OPTION** count is high probably because the MySQL library you are using issues a **SET** option command every time it creates a connection to the MySql server. Few libraries tend to set some basic options everytime they create a new connection. 
This could also happen if your system does a lot of transactions with MySQL.
However, this is pretty normal. I am using MySql 5.6.34 with PHP. Refer [image: stats_my_system]

Comment: Thanks Tarun. However its bit scary that the count increases so high drastically from one day without any change made.